# Reload Grid in ATK4

Tags: atk4

I'm trying to learn enough to create a website that lets people answer quiz questions using Agile Toolkit 4.2.

I have a page that displays one question and its answer choices from the 'sampleq' model.  I want to make a button that displays the next record in the model.

I've tried a bunch of different ways to get the js()->reload() command to work properly, but I haven't been able to do it.  I get AJAX "unexpected identifier" error.  I've been through the related questions on this site and looked for documentation on the ATK site, but I haven't found an example that works for me.

Can anybody tell me how to get the button to properly reload the grid?

```
function init(){
    parent::init();
    $page=$this;
}

function page_qlisting() {

    $qid=$this->recall('value',1);
    echo $qid;
    $NextB=$this->add('Button')->SetLabel('Next Question '.$qid);

    $grid=$this->add('Grid');
    $grid->setModel('sampleq',array('question','A1','A2','A3'));
    $grid->dq->where('id=',$qid);

        if($NextB->isClicked()){
            //$this->memorize('value',$qid+1);
            $grid->js()->reload();
        }               
  }

function page_qentry() {

$this->api->auth->check();
$this->add('Html')->set('Welcome to the question entry page.<br>');
$this->add('CRUD')->setModel('sampleq');
}
```

}

Edit:
After reading Romans' answer, I first tried this:

```
$qid=$this->recall('value',1);
    $grid=$this->add('Grid');
            $grid->setModel('sampleq',array('id','question','A1','A2','A3'));
            $grid->dq->where('id=',$qid);
            $this->add('Button')->SetLabel('Next Question')->js('click', $this->memorize('value',$qid+1))->js('click', $grid->js()->reload());
```

That actually works - it displays only one record at a time, and it displays the next one when I click the button.  Next I tried adding a "Previous" button like so:

```
$qid=$this->recall('value',1);
        $grid=$this->add('Grid');
        $grid->setModel('sampleq',array('id','question','A1','A2','A3'));
        $grid->dq->where('id=',$qid);
        $this->add('Button')->SetLabel('Previous Question')->js('click', $this->memorize('value',$qid-1))->js('click', $grid->js()->reload());
        $this->add('Button')->SetLabel('Next Question    ')->js('click', $this->memorize('value',$qid+1))->js('click', $grid->js()->reload());
```

This doesn't work, though.  Both buttons are decrementing.  I tried laying it out like your [adjuster buttons example here](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/view/interactive).  Here's what my increment button code looks like in that attempt:

```
$incr=$this->add('Button')->SetLabel('Next Question');
        if($incr->isClicked()){
           $this->memorize('value',$qid+1);
           $grid->js()->reload();
           }
```

In that case, I get "Error in AJAXec response: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when I click the button.

Can you offer any advice on how to make increment and decrement work with a grid (or crud)?  Why doesn't the adjuster example work when you try to refresh a grid instead of refreshing the button?  Thanks for the previous answer, and thanks in advance for any additional guidance that you may have time to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be it:

```
$this->add('Button')->js('click', $grid->js()->reload());
```

If you use CRUD you might want to reload CRUD instead.

Comment: That command works - thanks very much for listing that. I'm trying to create buttons that increment and decrement like in your example here: [link](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/view/interactive).  I'll edit the question and show how this is still not quite getting me there, but it is definitely an improvement.